# WebView2 - NavigateToString method returns "Operation Cancelled" error

Tags: c#, webview2

The `NavigateToString` method returns an error for any html string provided as a parameter.

The event handler for `NavigationCompleted` returns `Operation Canceled`. Most likely the initialization is incorrect or incomplete but nut sure what.

Can you please help with a working C# sample so I can learn how to use webview2?

```
async void InitializeAsync()
{
        var env = await   Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(userDataFolder: cacheDirectory);
        await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
        webView21.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right; //Fill
        webView21.NavigationStarting += EnsureHttps;
        webView21.NavigationCompleted += WebView21_NavigationCompleted;
  } 

...
...
webView21.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString("<html>HELLO!</html>"); //Fails
webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://www.google.com"); //Works
```

Comment: How about instead of asking volunteers to come up with a working example, you show them your non-working example, and they can can show you how to correct it? People searching the web for "Operation Canceled" error want to know how to fix it, not what a "perfect" request looks like.

Comment: My non working example has two lines of codes. I can past that in if you would like.Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show the code in `EnsureHttps`method.

Comment: I copied the `EnsureHttps` method from the Microsoft tutorial:  
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winui)

Comment: Ah, that explains it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can call `Navigate("https://www.google.com")` but not `NavigateToString("<html>HELLO!</html>")` the problem must be in the difference.

And that is most likely caused by your `EnsureHttps` method.

**When you use `NavigateToString` it's NOT `https`! The url of the new page is `about:blank`!**

So you should check that in your `EnsureHttps` method and not redirect/change url if the url is `about:blank`.

Comment: Poul Bak, i need to say that you are so smart. That was it!. I was focusing on the CoreWebView2 initialization and did not know that i put a trap to my self by insuring that the request is secure. Good job!